# Extra quotes in php return

Tags: php

I have this line of code

```
{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) == 'fa' || 'ar' ? "dir='rtl'" : "dir='ltr'" }}
```

it suppose to return `dir="rtl"` or `dir="ltr"` based on page language, but it does it like this

```
dir="'rtl'"
```

there are extra `' '` around `rtl` and `ltr` words.

Worth to mention, my code at the first was like this and it didn't work

```
{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) == 'fa' || 'ar' ? 'dir="rtl"' : 'dir="ltr"' }}
```

**Where did i make mistake in my code?**

Comment: btw, `app()->getLocale()) == 'fa' || 'ar'` <- this expression does not do what you think. If you want to compare a locale with 2 values - you must explicitly compare it with 2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I quite follow your code, but try the following and see if that fixes the issue:

```
{{ (str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) == 'fa') || (str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) == 'ar') ? "dir=rtl" : "dir=ltr" }}
```

I'm basically just replacing the single quote `'` with escaped double quotes `\"`.

Comment: it returns `syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'`

Comment: you had extra `)` here `'ar')` and when i removed it, it returns `dir='"ltr"'`

Comment: @mafortis it's hard to believe what you state actually

Comment: Sorry, I was a little confused by your code, try it again now.

Comment: with your code i get this now `<html dir=""rtl"" class="sr js" lang="fa">`

Comment: I presume you're feeding this in to a funky templating engine, and it's probably adding its own quotes around values. I completely stripped the values of quotation marks (because you technically don't need them), has this resolved your issue?

Comment: Cool. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
   <html dir= "{{ (str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) == 'fa') ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'}}" 
   lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
```